# In C# what type are integer literals?

Tags: c#, integer

I just notice if i pass a value such as 1 in a function parameter it will work if it excepts int, long and i assume the others. However if i do int i = value, it doesnt. I was wondering, what type is it?

Comment: Can you provide a code example, and the error that you're seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(1).GetType().ToString() //is System.Int32
```

Comment: For completeness, the original poster may want examples for 'L', 'U' and 'UL' as well maybe? :)

Answer (score 4):

You can suffix literal integers to make the type explicit, otherwise the value will be implicitly interpreted as though it were the target type (assuming it doesn't overflow the target).

```
var myLong = 123L;
var myInt = 123;
var myByte = (byte)123; // i'm not aware of a suffix for this one

// unsigned variants
var myULong = 123UL;
var myUInt = 123U;
```

Comment: Regarding the byte suffix your "un-awareness" is well founded; there is none ;o)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [integer literals specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(VS.71).aspx):

> The type of an integer literal is
>   determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which
>     its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by U or u, it has the first of these types
>     in which its value can be represented: uint, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by L or l, it has the first of these types
>     in which its value can be represented: long, ulong.
> - If the literal is suffixed by UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu, it
>     is of type ulong.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the compiler will use type-hinting to determine the type of the literal at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The type is determined.

If you have this function:

```
public void SomeFunc( long i );
```

and you call it like this:

```
SomeFunc (1);
```

Then C# will see this '1' as being a long.

Answer (score 0):

Integer literals are `int` per default, but since there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`, you can still call a method which take a `long` with an `int`.